# What's the right way of defining event handler in ReactJS Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

There are different ways of defining event handlers in ReactJS component with JSX syntax.

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input>  // inline binding
```

And

```
<input onChange={() => this.handleChange()}></input>  // using arrow function
```

Both allow `handleChange` function to access `this` scope of component.

I have been using the first syntax as it is more clear in readability.

Are there any advantages or use cases to use one over another?

Answer (score 3):

[From the React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick
    return (
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the property initializer syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

So, you should use `bind` and you can do that in two ways.

[From the React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

and if `bind` annoys you, then you can do it like this

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.
  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

The only advantage that I can think of for using one over the other is that in the top approach you can pass parameters to the `handleClick` function. But I can't think of a situation on where you might do that.

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
  }

  handleClick(e, something) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
    alert(something)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "Yo!")}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind functions in the constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

But the best way is define your method with arrow function:

`handleChange = () => {}`

In this variant you will run bind each time when component will render:

`<input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input>`

Arrow function is used when you need to pass something to your method:

`<input onChange={() => this.handleChange(params)}></input>`

Because:

`<input onChange={this.handleChange(params)}></input>`

Will fire when component will render.

Check this [arcticle](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56).